# Parse multiple fields from console input by using regex groups

Tags: java, regex, console, console-application

I have `Publication` entity:

```
public class Publication {
    private long id;
    private String authorName;
    private Topic topic;
    private long publicationTime;
    private String header;
    private String text;
//...
}
```

where `Topic` is enum and has preinstalled values:

```
public enum Topic {
    SALE, PURCHASE, RENT, SERVICES, DATING;
}
```

Rules for `Publication` entity:

1. Author name can contain latin letters and digits, but the first symbol should be a letter. Its length should be in range from 4 to 20 symbols.
2. User should choose one of preinstalled topics.
3. Header should contain from 10 to 30 symbols.
4. Text should contain from 20 to 400 symbols.

User works through console and can edit publications.

This is a syntax user should use:
`[author name] [topic] [header] [text]`

where fields separated from each other by whitespace.

So I came up with the following regex:

`([a-zA-Z]\\w{3,19}) (RENT|SALE|PURCHASE|SERVICES|DATING) ((\\w|\\W|\\s){10,30}) ((\\w|\\W|\\s){20,400})`

And I'm parsing as:

```
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("above regex");
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
         if (matcher.find()) {
            String authorName = matcher.group(1);
            Topic topic = Topic.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
            String header = matcher.group(3);
            String text = matcher.group(4);
            //...
         }
```

But it fails for example for such input:

```
Alexander SALE some header This is a text for some publication
```

Because Matcher founds more then four groups and so I'me getting:

```
authorName=Alexander
topic=SALE
header=header three This is a
text=a
```

Instead of:

```
authorName=Alexander
topic=SALE
header=header three
text=This is a text for some publication
```

How it can be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ambiguous input format, so you will never parse this successfully. You cannot determine where `[header]` ends and `[text]` begins, because you are allowing space characters in both values.

I recommend you change to a delimiter that isn't allowed in the input data (e.g. `;` or `/`). Or perhaps require that the header is encapsulated in something you can search for, e.g

```
Alexander SALE {some header} This is a text for some publication
```

If you used my second example, the following pattern then matches it:

```
"([a-zA-Z]\\w{3,19}) (RENT|SALE|PURCHASE|SERVICES|DATING) \\{((?:\\w|\\W|\\s){10,30})\\} ((\\w|\\W|\\s){20,400})"
```

In addition to adding the `\\{...\\}` to capture the title, I also corrected a part of your pattern. Originally you had:

```
((\\w|\\W|\\s){10,30})
```

But this creates two capturing groups. To avoid this, I made the inner group a *non-capturing* group with the addition of `?:`, as shown below:

```
((?:\\w|\\W|\\s){10,30})
```

Comment: would you suggest a couple ?

Comment: yes, I took your advice. I've also tried your regex and it works good. thank you! ps. would you explain what means `?:` beetwen `\\w|\\W|\\s` ?

Comment: @Mark I added some explanation above. To understand more, research "non-capturing groups".